# How to decouple multithreading logic from actual business logic

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have 2 service calls which I want to run in parallel. Right now code is simply like

```
a.service1()
b.service2()
```

I used callable interface to run this process in parallel

```
List callables = newArrayList();

callables.add(new Callable() {
   public Object call() throws Exception {
    a.service1();
   }
});

callables.add(new Callable() {
   public Object call() throws Exception {
    b.service2();
   }
});


ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(callables.size());

List futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);

for(Future future : futures) {
...
}


executor.shutdown();
```

But this has multithreading & business logic at one place only & I want to segregate that.

Comment: This depends on how complex your problem really is and how much complexity is worth the benefit. Spring Integration handles situations like this well but might be overkill.

Comment: These 2 processes are not dependent. They make separate web services calls so I want to make them parallel.This is the only requirement.

Comment: Spring AOP `@Async`?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like you've mixed business logic and execution logic to me, although perhaps I have misunderstood what your example represents.

If all your business logic is encapsulated inside a.service1() and b.service2(), the code you have posted merely controls the execution of this logic.

So you can test each set of logic (with external service dependencies) and also invoke them from other contexts without altering their meaning or behaviour, in this example you just invoke them both in parallel, which is a decision of the calling code.

A more concrete example (as in real service names and real method names) might make your question clearer.